# Does SQL Server optimize LIKE ('%%') query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, stored-procedures, sql-like

I have a Stored Proc which performs search on records.

The problem is that some of the search criteria,which are coming from UI, may be empty string.
So, when the criteria not specified, the LIKE statement becomes redundant.

How can I effectively perform that search or Sql Server? Or, Does it optimize LIKE('%%') query since it means there is nothing to compare?

The Stored proc is like this:

```
ALTER PROC [FRA].[MCC_SEARCH]
@MCC_Code varchar(4),
@MCC_Desc nvarchar(50),
@Detail nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN             
       SELECT
             MCC_Code,
             MCC_Desc,
             CreateDate,
             CreatingUser

       FROM
              FRA.MCC (NOLOCK)
       WHERE
             MCC_Code LIKE ('%' + @MCC_Code + '%')
             AND MCC_Desc LIKE ('%' + @MCC_Desc + '%')
             AND Detail LIKE ('%' + @Detail + '%')
       ORDER BY MCC_Code

END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is - **no**
The long answer is - **absolutely not**

> Does it optimize LIKE('%%') query since it means there is nothing to compare?

The statement is **untrue**, because there *is* something to compare. The following are equivalent

```
WHERE column LIKE '%%'
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

IS NOT NULL requires a table scan, unless there are very few non-null values in the column and it is well indexed.

#### EDIT

Resource on Dynamic Search procedures in SQL Server:
You simply **must** read this article by Erland Sommarskog, SQL Server MVP http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html (pick your version, or read both)

Otherwise if you need good performance on CONTAINS style searches, consider using SQL Server Fulltext engine.

Comment: This is incorrect, LIKE can be optimized even when searching in the middle of the field. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/26/getting-an-index-seek-to-speed-up-like-string-searches/

Answer (score 5):

With regard to an optimal, index-using execution plan - no. The prefixing wildcard prevents an index from being used, resulting in a scan instead.

If you do not have a wildcard on the end of the search term as well, then that scenario can be optimised - something I blogged out a while back: [Optimising wildcard prefixed LIKE conditions](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/05/optimising-like-conditions-with.html)

**Update**
To clarify my point:
LIKE 'Something%' - is able to use an index 
LIKE '%Something' - is not able to use an index out-of-the-box. But you can optimise this to allow it to use an index by following the "REVERSE technique" I linked to.
LIKE '%Something%' - is not able to use an index. Nothing you can do to optimise for LIKE.

Comment: @Richard - no, I mean "on the end". i.e. LIKE '%Something' - as there's no wildcard on the end of that condition, it is possible to optimise that, per my blog - basically, REVERSE the column value into a computed column, then REVERSE the search term which ends up having the % on the end and therefore can use index.

Comment: @Richard - You're talking about a different scenario - I'm specifically talking about when you want to find items that *end* with a given string (LIKE '%Something') which will not use an index (unless you follow an approach like what I blogged about). You're talking about finding items that *start* with a given string (LIKE 'Something%') which of course can make use on indexes without any REVERSE-ing.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, I know - I added it as a secondary point **after** addressing the specific Q the OP was asking, as I felt it may add value to people who read this Q now and in future. So was just trying to highlight, in a nutshell, that "%Something" can be optimised (as not everyone is aware of that) as can "Something%" ...whereas "%Something%" cannot be optimised with LIKE. Went with the link to the full reference, and not much detail here specifically because it was not a direct answer to the specific Q.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a LIKE clausule, and specify a wildcard-character (%) as a prefix of the searchstring, SQL Server (and all other DBMS'es I guess) will not be able to use indexes that might exists on that column.

I don't know if it optimizes the query if you use an empty search-argument ... Perhaps your question may be answered if you look at the execution plan ?

Edit: I've just checked this out, and the execution plan of this statement:

```
select * from mytable
```

is exactly the same as this the exec plan of this statement:

```
select * from mytable where description like '%'
```

Both SQL statements simply use a clustered index scan.

Comment: True for this case but using the `LIKE` clause *prevents* the optimizer from using an other index. If you do a `select <indexed column>` and a `select <indexed column> where ...%`, you'll get different execution plans.

Comment: Obviously, since select <indexed column> from <table> will always result in an index scan, since the index is completely covered.

Comment: You (or I) are missing the point. Reading your answer, OP might conclude there is no performance penalty when in reality, there might be. Imagine your query only has to return *one* *indexed* column. Adding to this query a *where %%* clause on another column will be a performance overhead.

Comment: What you're saying is indeed correct.  But, in the actual case that is brought up by the question-asker, I think that it is quite obvious since he's selecting the columns that are in his where clause, and I think the same index will always be used, regardless whether he uses a where %% clause , or not. (In fact, we don't know if the topicstarter has indexes on the detail column for instance, 'cause this could indeed be a column which will affect the exec plan)