# How scalable is using .Contains for searching and auto-complete search in asp.net MVc web applications

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, contains

i have found a lot of tutorials and books that implements the auto-complete search in MVC web applications as in :-

```
public ActionResult ArtistSearch(string q)
{
var artists = GetArtists(q);
return PartialView(artists);
}
private List<Artist> GetArtists(string searchString)
{
return storeDB.Artists
.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(searchString))
.ToList();
}
```

but this raised a question of how much is this approach scalable in real applications that might have thousands of records ???,, so will using Contains() scale well Or there is a much better approach??
BR

Comment: Why don't you just test it out on large data sets?

Comment: Depends on your schema and the amount of data. For large data sets, I'd probably hit a cache instead of the DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly `string.Contains()` is translated into a LIKE Query with a wildcard on each side of the query string. This makes it very difficult/impossible to use an index, so you can expect your performance to be O(n) on your dataset since SQL Server does a full table scan (see [Does SQL Server optimize LIKE ('%%') query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039705/does-sql-server-optimize-like-query)).

To optmize your query, you might want to take a look at the Full-Text Indexing Capabilities, more info here: [SQL Server: how to optimize "like" queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532075/sql-server-how-to-optimize-like-queries)).

If you could use `.StartsWith` instead of .Contains you will have a LIKE query with a wildcard at the end, and you can use an Index on the queried column to get fast lookups (be sure to check the query execution plan!).

I guess you will have much better perceived performance if you try to focus on the UX of your auto-complete feature: Start auto-complete search after a short lock period (when the user stops typing), and make sure it doesn't block (happens in the background).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data your serving. In a "real world" application, you need to think about noise/stop words ("and", "the"), abbreviations ("st" for "street"), etc and difficult languages.

In these scenarios, `.Contains` won't fit the bill, and you'll need to employ a full-text search indexing engine, such as Lucene.NET or SQL Server Full Text Search.

Answer (score 0):

Substring queries cannot use index seeks. But they still can use indexes. Scanning a few thousand records is really nothing if you don't do it too often.

So I recommend that you create an index on `Name` and you'll be fine for an awful lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using LINQ with the Entity Framework. LINQ gets converted into SQL and the call to contains gets converted into a LIKE WHERE clause, so you can simply run `SELECT * FROM Artists WHERE Name LIKE '%whatever%'` to get an idea about performance.

Note there are a couple of things you can do to reduce the impact. One you can limit the number of results `.Take(20)`. Also you can wait until the user takes at least a couple of characters before triggering auto complete. Finally you can 'throttle' the call to auto complete, so that you don't call auto complete every time they type a character, instead of wait until they go say a half a second without typing an additional character.